# How to convert a query using QueryParser to the programmatic way?

Tags: java, lucene

I am currently using the QueryParser method of searching, but I don't want to give the end user so much control.

So currently if they are searching for a work like this:

```
The*
```

I will just pass that into the QueryParser.parse() method.

Now in my UI I will have a input box that says "Starts With" and let them enter the text.

How would I create a search query that would then search based on the above?  (I will have other input boxes for other things like min/max length etc.)

Comment: so you wanna do wildcard searches automatically? like every term will ending with a wildcard?

Answer (score 2):

PrefixQuery is what you are looking for -

```
new PrefixQuery(new Term("inputIndex","searchstring"));
```

This will return all documents indexed with field 'inputIndex' having value starting with "searchstring".

```
searcher.search(new PrefixQuery(new Term("inputIndex","searchstring")));
```